# How would I use an anonymous result type for an expression delegate for LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, delegates

I have an existing LINQ to SQL query, where I'm trying to allow for different groupings:

```
var result= dc.Report_Data
                .Where(x => x.Year == Year)
                .Where(x => x.Month >= Month)
                .GroupBy(grouping)
                .Select(g => new ReportViewModel(){
                    Month = g.Key.Month,
                    Option1 = g.Key.Option1, 
                    Option2 = g.Key.Option2,
                    Amount = g.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                })
                .ToList();
```

I need to allow a different sets of properties to group by, based on an external parameter. I set a default value, then use conditionals like this:

```
Expression<Func<Report_Data, TResult>> grouping = g => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop1, Option2 = g.prop2};

if (userParameter == "X"){
    grouping = g => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop3, Option2 = g.prop4};
} else if (userParameter == "Y") {
    grouping = g => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop5, Option2 = g.prop6};
}
```

Then I'm passing `grouping` into the querty above. The problem is that I have an anonymous type in the grouping and `Expression<Func<Report_Data, TResult>>` errors when I use `TResult` as the Result Type.

Is there a way to use this expression delegate format and specify a generic or anonymous result type? (preferably without having to create a class for every result type)
Or should I be allowing different groupings by some other mechanism?

Comment: Most problems with anonymous types you can work around by defining your own named type. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you construct to different anonymous types here, cause you define it at two places. But to assign it to grouping, they must be equal.

Instead of having the grouping as variable, you can also put your "if" in the chain of IQueryable<Report_Data>.

Comment: I don't disagree. The reason I'm trying to stick with generics if possible is because this is an existing code base that I'm modifying and there are multiple queries I will be updating that are all using anonymous types. So if I can get away with changing less, I'd like to do that. If it proves to be worse in the end, I'll go through and start creating a bunch of named types.

Comment: You can't have a (non-generic) method return an anonymous type, and you can't step back (or up) a level because `Grouping` returns an `IGrouping` that depends on the anonymous type as well. But you could standardize the key type by making `Option1` and `Option2` a fixed type and converting the various `prop*` fields to that type if they aren't already similar. What are the types of `ReportViewModel.Option1` and `ReportViewModel.Option2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following an explanation from this blog post on [building LINQ Queries](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx/), I was find a solution as follows:

Extend LINQ:

```
public static class Linq {
    public static Expression<Func<T, R>> 
        Expr<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> f) {
        return f;
    }
}
```

The grouping can then be set like this:

```
var grouping = Linq.Expr((Report_Data g) => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop1, Option2 = g.prop2});

if (userParameter == "X") {
    grouping = Linq.Expr((Report_Data g) => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop3, Option2 = g.prop4});
} else if(userParameter == "Y") {
    grouping = Linq.Expr((Report_Data g) => new {g.Month, Option1 = g.prop5, Option2 = g.prop6});
}
```